# Using find in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to check if a given string in a bash script is a command.
In other words: I need to check if that String is a filename in the /bin directory (Only /bin).

I tried

```
echo "Write a bash command: "

read -r var2

if [[ -z (find /bin -name $var2) ]]
    then echo "That's not a command" && exit 1

fi
```

But it didn't work.

Ideas?

EDIT: Solved. As amdixon suggested I changed (find /bin -name $var2) for $(find /bin -name $var2).

Thanks dude.

Comment: change `(find /bin -name $var2)` to `$(find /bin -name $var2)`

Comment: `which $var2` will tell you if the command is found, and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual requirements, it can be easier than that:

```
if ! [ -x /bin/"$var2" ]
then
    echo "That's not a command" && exit 1
fi
```

`[` is short for the `test` command and with the `-x` argument, it will return `0` (true) if the given file is executable by you. Note that this will exclude commands that are executable by other users only because you have insufficient permissions.

If you use the `-f` argument instead, `[` will test for any file in the `/bin` directory, whether it is executable or not (of course usually all of them are):

```
if ! [ -f /bin/"$var2" ]
then
    echo "That's not a command" && exit 1
fi
```

If you need to make sure that the file is executable (even if it may not be executable by you), see [this question](http://tp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319652/check-if-a-file-is-executable) for a solution using `file`.

Type `help test` on the command line to read more about possible arguments for `[`.

Comment: What  `-f` and `-x` do?

Comment: @Argos: I'll add a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Write a bash command: "

read -r var2

if [ ! -f /bin/"$var2" ]
    then echo "That's not a command" && exit 1
fi
```

is the *natural* way to do this in bash. `[ expr ]` is the shorthand for the builtin `test` command. Type man `builtins` and scroll until you find `test` for a complete description of what `test`can do for you. For instance, if you prefer testing simultaneously if the file exists and is executable, you can replace:

```
[ ! -f /bin/"$var2" ]
```

by:

```
[ ! -x /bin/"$var2" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check if a given string in a bash script is a command.

vs

> I need to check if that String is a filename in the /bin directory (Only /bin).

This is *by no means* the same. I guess you refer to well-known "shell commands" and in this case, There are three reasons you might be on the wrong path:

1. The root hierarchy is for everything needed to boot up the system. This might include what you consider "commands", but other stuff as well (like e.g. `lvm` or `cryptsetup`)
2. For the same reason, binaries you would consider "commands" might be missing from /bin, living in /usr/bin instead.
3. Shells have "builtin" commands and there is no guarantee you will find them as separate binaries at all.

Given all that, if you still want to look for executables in /bin, there is really no reason to use `find` at all. `test` (or the abbreviated version just writing brackets) will be enough, like `if [ -x /bin/$var2 ]; then` ...

Comment: Don't think this is what the question was asking.

Comment: The question is asking about two *different* requirements (assumed to be the same, which I try to clarify here) and presents a needlessly complicated solution to the second requirement (`find` really is not necessary here). But of course you could just point out how it is used wrongly ...